# angular 2 cannot access array of objects from json

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I am connecting my app with an API. whenever I do a post request, I will get a json back that looks like this

```
 {
 "output": {
   "text": {
     "values": [
       "Sure ! What kind of mouse would you like"
     ],
     "selection_policy": "sequential"
   },
   "cards": [
     {
       "Mouse_Type": "Wireless"

     },
     {
       "Mouse_Type": "Optical"

     }
   ]
 }
}
```

in my html I have created this:

```
 <ul class="cards-options">
        <li *ngFor="let options of listOptions" >

          <span class="card">
            <p>{{options.Mouse_Type }}</p>
          </span> 
        </li>
      </ul>
```

my component is like this:

```
export class InputFieldComponent implements OnInit {

  value = '';
  listOptions = '';

  public context :object;

  constructor(private http : Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onEnter(value: string) {  
    this.http.post('/APIconversation', {"input":value })
      .map(response=>response.json())
      .subscribe(
          data => {            
                this.listOptions = data.output.cards;
                console.log(this.listOptions);
          }
      )
   }
```

Whenever I inspect the element of the *ngFor I find this:

bindings={   "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object
 Object" }

How can I access the string within the object? I did the same exact thing with another API and it was working. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you doing `listOptions = '';`, shouldn't that be `listOptions = [];`?

Comment: what do you get here `console.log(this.listOptions);`

Comment: thank you so much @peinearydevelopment that was exactly my issue!!!